# Append string to head using JavaScript and execute

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script that I am using to append a string to the `head` tag, it works, but it doesn't execute what was appended.

`HTML` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

File: `test.js`

```
var str =
`
<script ... ></script>
<link...>
other stuff...
`

var html = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML=str+html;
```

With this, I understand that it would go into recursion if all of `head` was executed again just to execute the appended string (unless there is a way to execute *only* the appended string), but I have a way to deal with this. First, I need it to actually execute.

I have seen other similar questions, but they ask about appending a single `script` tag or something similar, I'm looking to add a whole chunk of `HTML` and have the browser execute it.

I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution.

Note that `str` contains things like `JQuery` and `Bootstrap` and therefore the rest of the document heavily depends on this append & execution happening first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting scripts via `innerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML()`, etc. doesn't run them. To do that, we have to be a bit more creative; see inline comments:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const str =
  `
  <script>console.log("Hello from script")<\/script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  `;

  // Create an element outside the document to parse the string with
  const head = document.createElement("head");

  // Parse the string
  head.innerHTML = str;

  // Copy those nodes to the real `head`, duplicating script elements so
  // they get processed
  let node = head.firstChild;
  while (node) {
    const next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.tagName === "SCRIPT") {
      // Just appending this element wouldn't run it, we have to make a fresh copy
      const newNode = document.createElement("script");
      if (node.src) {
        newNode.src = node.src;
      }
      while (node.firstChild) {
        // Note we have to clone these nodes
        newNode.appendChild(node.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
      }
      node = newNode;
    }
    document.head.appendChild(node);
    node = next;
  }
}, 800);
```

```html
The appearance of <input type="button" value="this button"> changes when Bootstrap's CSS is loaded
```

The Bootstrap CSS is just there to demonstrate that the `link` is working. The timeout is just so you can *see* the `link` take effect.

Also note the backslash in the `<\/script>` tag in the string. We only need that because that string is within a `<script>...</script>` tag. We wouldn't need it if this were in a `.js` file.

Tested in current Chrome and Firefox. A [version using a plain string instead of a template literal](https://jsfiddle.net/7moLr8tq/) works in IE11, too.

We could do much the same with `DOMParser` instead of a freestanding `head` element. Instead of:

```
// Create an element outside the document to parse the string with
const head = document.createElement("head");

// Parse the string
head.innerHTML = str;
```

you'd use

```
// Parse the HTML and get the resulting head element.
// You could probably get away without the wrapper markup, but let's
// include it for completeness.
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString("<!doctype html><html><head>" + str + "</head></html>", "text/html");
const head = doc.head;
```

The rest is the same:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const str =
  `
  <script>console.log("Hello from script")<\/script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  `;

// Parse the HTML and get the resulting head element.
// You could probably get away without the wrapper markup, but let's
// include it for completeness.
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString("<!doctype html><html><head>" + str + "</head></html>", "text/html");
const head = doc.head;

  // Copy those nodes to the real `head`, duplicating script elements so
  // they get processed
  let node = head.firstChild;
  while (node) {
    const next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.tagName === "SCRIPT") {
      // Just appending this element wouldn't run it, we have to make a fresh copy
      const newNode = document.createElement("script");
      if (node.src) {
        newNode.src = node.src;
      }
      while (node.firstChild) {
        // Note we have to clone these nodes
        newNode.appendChild(node.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
      }
      node = newNode;
    }
    document.head.appendChild(node);
    node = next;
  }
}, 800);
```

```html
The appearance of <input type="button" value="this button"> changes when Bootstrap's CSS is loaded
```

Comment: It works, but only sometimes. Even with a timeout (on things that use JQuery), I occasionally get an error because something that uses `JQuery` can't find it. And the timeout solution isn't the best thing either, because its noticeable, one minute the page is text only, and then all of a sudden everything is styled and in position.

Comment: Any ideas why this happens? - sometimes it can find `JQuery` and sometimes it can't?

Comment: @sudoman: In that case, you'll have to hook the `load` and `error` events (**before** setting `src`) on each script, and wait to append subsequent nodes until you get the `load` or `error` callback. Not trivial, but not difficult.

Comment: @sudoman: Listening for both `error` and `load`, and I'd use `addEventListener` (although you could probably get away with `onload` and `onerror`), but yes. :-) Again be sure you hook the events before setting `src`, it's critical.

Comment: will having an event listener for each node added affect performance at all?

Comment: @sudoman: "hook the event" = attach a handler for the event. E.g., using `addEventListener` or setting `onxyz`.

Comment: @sudoman: Not in any way that will mean anything, you're only hooking one-time events on `script` elements.

Comment: A `<script>` tag with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){...},false);` does not work as it normally would. Maybe because the `event` was missed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139979/discussion-between-sudoman-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @sudoman: Yes, DOMContentLoaded would have fired long, long before. As will the `window` `load` event.

Comment: I've managed to kind of get a work around going by dispatching my own event when the loading completes and then doing that `script` tag, but for some reason I get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched`. If i add a timeout, this error message goes away and all is good, why does this happen?

Comment: @sudoman: I don't know (though the message is fairly clear, could you be firing this in a handler for DOMContentLoaded?). At this point, we're far afield from the original question. I suggest packaging up the issue you're having in an MCVE and posting a question about it.